# ASP.NET MVC3 model with list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, validation

I have a minor problem in MVC 3. I'm creating an application, where my model, a shipment, consists of the following:

- a user id (string, required)
- a reference id (string, optional)
- a list of order ids (strings, cannot be empty)

The index view of the application is where the user creates the shipment (model). Once this is done, the user has no further interaction with it (no edit, detail or list views).

My problem is this. I'm trying to use one form for both adding order ids, and for creating the shipment itself, using two separate buttons for submitting ("Add" for adding order ids, "Send" for creating the shipment). It seems that when I'm using the Create-action of my controller, that pressing "Send" overwrites my list of order ids with an empty one. However, if I'm submitting to the Index-action, and redirecting to Create on a press of "Send", my model validation is gone (ModelState only contains "submit").

Right now I'm using sessions to pass data around my controller actions, which is probably not the best way to do it.

TLDR; I need a way to add items to a list in a model, one at a time, while persisting other form data, and still be able to validate it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help if you add your form's and controllers code ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to take a look on your Actions, because it's not quite clear what are you doing there, but still it looks like you are tring to use same data structure to pass different tipes of parameters (one contains list, another contains general data). I think it's better to submit different data structures and build required result data object in each action.